# Dealing with outlier in a MFFC with DTW setup

Tags: pattern-matching, speech-recognition, mfcc

I have a small command recognition system in which the user first records his commands then later the system tries to recognize them . The front end's feature vector are MFCC's coefficients.  The back end does recognition using DTW to align these feature vector and outputting a score ( 0 -> commands are equal). The problem with this setup is distinguishing commands (the ones which the user recorded) from other words. Picking a maximum score as threshold for which commands are recognized doesn't give good results. I looked up LDA and PCA with the purpose of projecting the recorded features to a different feature space where they could be more separable. Each recorded command is a class that has as samples feature vectors from the front-end associated with the frame of that command. From that I computed the transformation required for LDA, and applied the transformation to each set of resulting MFCC coefficients. That didn't give me a separability between recorded commands and urecorded commands.

My questions would be:

- is the approach in applying LDA the wrong one?
- are there other methods more suited for my setup (MFCC + DTW)?

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> The problem with this setup is distinguishing commands that were not recorded.

You probably want to express better that you want to separate keywords you are looking for from all other possible words. It's not clear what do you mean by "that were not recorded"

> is the approach in applying LDA the wrong one?

It's not wrong, it's meaningless. The PCA optimizes different properties and by no mean could improve separation.

> Picking a maximum score as threshold for which commands are recognized doesn't give good results.

This approach is not the best possible one but it should work relatively well. It was proven over ages. You probably just made a mistake in it's implementation or testing or there is some other bug. I suggest you to revisit it.

The only thing you need to know is that threshold has to be dependent on template keyword. So for different template keywords threshold has to be different. A single threshold will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried using a threshold for each keyword by picking the maximum score between that keyword and every other keywords. It doesn't give good results in noise conditions. I also tried for each keyword picking the maximum score obtained by matching that keyword (in clean conditions) with the rest of the keywords only the later are spoken in noise conditions. While not doable in a real world scenario it gives good results. is there some way to make use of this knowledge?